# AutoMapper: Build destination from two properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string[] Bookmarks { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEntry
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEntryWithBookmarks
{
    public PersonEntry Entry { get; set; }
    public string[] Bookmarks { get; set; } 
}
```

And I want to create the following mapping:

```
Mapper.Map<PersonEntryWithBookmarks, Person>(person)
```

How do I map the `Entry` property from the source to all the properties in `Person` (besides `Bookmarks`) and the `Bookmarks` property from the source to the `Bookmarks` property in Person?

Comment: This is not Java, ain't that rather C# (auto properties and lower case string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonEntry, Person>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonEntryWithBookmarks, Person>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => Mapper.Map<PersonEntry, Person>(src.Entry, dest));

var person = Mapper.Map<PersonEntryWithBookmarks, Person>(personEntryWithBookmarks);
```

Bookmarks will be mapped for you automatically.

Comment: My PersonEntry and Person has a lot of common properties (I've just wrote FirstName and LastName in the question for simplicity) which makes me call ForMember multiple times, is there a way to map those automatically?

Comment: Changed the snippet to create a map from PersonEntry to Person and then use that mapping in the main mapping.

Comment: If you want AutoMapper to do it for you by convention then prefix FirstName, LastName etc. in the Person class with Entry (name of the property in the source class)